# Force changing database.yml params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

How I can change params that be set into database.yml?
For example: encoding param into datavase.yml is utf8 but I need set it equal utfmb4 but I cant change database.yml file. How I can do it?
May be into config/application.rb file with config.active_record.?

Comment: How about create another database_yours.yml and override the default database configuration, see this: https://gist.github.com/ejstembler/1418782

Answer (score 0):

We can change database.yml to other filename.
Paste it Into config/application.rb on line 11 (after define bundler)

```
module Rails
  class Application
    class Configuration < ::Rails::Engine::Configuration
      def paths
        @paths ||= begin
          paths = super
          paths.add "config/database",    with: "config/database_actual.yml"
          paths.add "config/environment", with: "config/environment.rb"
          paths.add "lib/templates"
          paths.add "log",                with: "log/#{Rails.env}.log"
          paths.add "public"
          paths.add "public/javascripts"
          paths.add "public/stylesheets"
          paths.add "tmp"
          paths
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And move database.yml to config/database_actual.yml